# How to make the output of NetTrain obey constraints?

Tags: neural-networks

Imagine I have this

```
     trained = NetTrain[LinearLayer[], {1 -> {0.1,0.7,0.2}, 2 -> 
     {0,0,1}, 3 -> {0.4,0.4,0.2}, 4 -> {0.1,0.0,0.9}}]
```

I want to make sure that trained[5] or even trained[1] itself, ALWAYS
gives an output like {a,b,c} where a+b+c = 1 and a,b,c
are between 0 and 1.

Comment: That's what the `SoftmaxLayer` is for.

Comment: Please give me the actual code that uses this for this purpose ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To follow up from my comment: training networks that output probability vectors is such a common use case that there is a standard way to do it. Any `NetChain` that ends with `SoftmaxLayer` will always produce an output vector (of non-negative values) that sums to one:

```
trained = NetTrain[
  NetChain[{LinearLayer[], SoftmaxLayer[]}], 
  {1 -> {0.1, 0.7, 0.2}, 2 -> {0, 0, 1}, 3 -> {0.4, 0.4, 0.2}, 4 -> {0.1, 0.0, 0.9}}
]
```

Check:

```
trained[RandomReal[1, {5}]]
Total /@ %
```

> {{0.40406, 0.397489, 0.198451}, {0.353724, 0.35222,  0.294056}, {0.394641, 0.389201, 0.216158}, {0.341313, 0.340755,  0.317933}, {0.348998, 0.347866, 0.303136}}

> {1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}

Comment: Does this method guarantee that each element of the output is going to be between 0 and 1 not just sum to 1 ?

Comment: Yes, a `SoftmaxLayer` always produces vector of probabilities. That's what it's made for.

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful.